# How to rename files using os.walk()?

Tags: python, file-rename, os.walk

I'm trying to rename a number of files stored within subdirectories by removing the last four characters in their basename. I normally use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to locate and rename files in **one directory** using:

```
import glob, os

for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/username/Desktop/Original data/" + "*.*"):
    pieces = list(os.path.splitext(file))
    pieces[0] = pieces[0][:-4]
    newFile = "".join(pieces)       
    os.rename(file,newFile)
```

But now I want to repeat the above in all subdirectories. I tried using [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/username/Desktop/Original data/"):
    for file in files:
        pieces = list(os.path.splitext(file))
        pieces[0] = pieces[0][:-4]
        newFile = "".join(pieces)       
        # print "Original filename: " + file, " || New filename: " + newFile
        os.rename(file,newFile)
```

---

The `print` statement correctly prints the original and the new filenames that I am looking for but `os.rename(file,newFile)` returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 7, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

How could I resolve this?

Comment: I believe you should pass on the os.raname the full path of the file also since your are not at the same directory as the walk...

Comment: @RafaelRodrigoDeSouza - Thanks, you are correct as described by niemmi's answer =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to pass the full path of the file to [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename). First item of the `tuple` returned by [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) is the current path so just use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to combine it with file name:

```
import os

for path, dirs, files in os.walk("./data"):
    for file in files:
        pieces = list(os.path.splitext(file))
        pieces[0] = pieces[0][:-4]
        newFile = "".join(pieces)
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, newFile))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your answer :)